# Ruby on Rails form_tag parameters missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, variables, date, jasper-reports

I have a form that takes date range value to generate a report with Jasper Reports

**reports/statistic.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag("/reports/statistic", :method => "post", :target => "_blank") do %>

  <%= label_tag(:from_date, "From Date:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :from_date %>

  <%= label_tag(:to_date, "To Date:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :to_date %>

  <br><br>
  <%= submit_tag("Generate Report") %>
<% end %>
```

and this is **reports_controller.rb**

```
def statistic

    @details=StatisticTable.where(:dateindb => (params[:from_date])..(params[:to_date])

    send_doc(render_to_string(
        :template => 'reports/statistic.xml', :layout => false),  #source of xml and template
        '/statistic/detail', #xml xpath2 query in reports
        'statisticreport',   #name of .jasper file
        'StatisticReport',   #name of pdf file
        'pdf')
  end
```

When I clicked Generate Report button, the report displays nicely in a pdf viewer in a new window. But when I try to save the pdf file, the pdf is empty and the date value is returned as null.

Also, I followed this tutorial http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoIntegrateJasperReports which explains where the send_doc method comes from.

I don't think the problem is in Jasper because if I replace this

```
@details=StatisticTable.where(:dateindb => (params[:from_date])..(params[:to_date])
```

with a pre-defined date value

```
@details=StatisticTable.where(:dateindb => ('2011-12-01')..('2011-12-31')
```

the report displays and saves perfectly. So I'm guessing there is something wrong with my Ruby on Rails variables setting?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the format of the dates is incomptible or the params aren't set how you think? What happens if you output `<=% "#{ params[:from_date] params[:to_date] }" %>`?

Comment: when I     puts(params[:from_date]) and puts(params[:to_date]) they displayed the date captured at the form, but from the report, when I click Save in the new displayed report, the date are returned as null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by only changing form method to GET

```
<%= form_tag("/reports/statistic", :method => "get", :target => "_blank") do %>

  <%= label_tag(:from_date, "From Date:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :from_date %>

  <%= label_tag(:to_date, "To Date:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :to_date %>

  <br><br>
  <%= submit_tag("Generate Report") %>
<% end %>
```

and after report is generated in PDF, I clicked Save and the PDF saves the whole data perfectly.